# C# Default Value at Method - compile error : compile-time constant

Tags: c#, xna, default-value

```
private static Vector2 DefaultMulFactors = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
private static Point DefaultShifts = new Point(0,0);

public static Vector2 Function(Vector2? mulFactors = MyClass.DefaultMulFactors , Point? shifts = MyClass.DefaultShifts  )
{ 
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Why does my code not accept my static values? How can I assign default parameters to my function parameters?  Indeed `Vector2? mulFactors = new Vector(0.2,0.3)` or `Vector2? mulFactors = Vector2.Zero` does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, basically. The value must be supported by the compiler to allow that type of usage (it is essentially a *constant*). I would just use `null` here:

```
, Point? shifts = null)
```

then:

```
if(shifts == null) shifts = MyClass.DefaultShifts;
```

Comment: Or even shorter `shifts = shifts ?? MyClass.DefaultShifts;`

Comment: i know this solution, but what i was trying not to use an if-else block :) thanks for answer Marc.

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN:

> Each optional parameter has a default value as part of its definition.
>   If no argument is sent for that parameter, the default value is used.
>   A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> a constant expression;
>
> an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value
>   type, such as an enum or a struct;
>
> an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value
>   type.

No one of mentioned cases is yours, that's why it doesn't work for you! :)